# Cómo configuro el usuario y correo por proyecto en Git

Tags: git

Tengo dos proyectos que usan `git` para el control de versiones, `proyectoA` y `proyectoB`, y para cada proyecto necesito los siguientes usuarios:

`ProyectoA` -> user_for_A *"user_for_A@mail"*

`ProyectoB` -> user_for_B *"user_for_B@mail"*

Mi pregunta es ¿Qué necesito hacer para tener diferentes usuarios git en cada proyecto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ve al repositorio que quieras hacerlo y luego utiliza:

```
git config user.name "nombre de usuario"
```

Answer (score 4):

Git te permite tener configuración a nivel global (para todos los proyectos) y a nivel particular (en cada proyecto).

### **Configuración Particular del Proyecto:**

Para configurar un nombre de usuario y email para cada proyecto, te posicionas dentro de la carpeta raíz del repositorio (o cualquier subcarpeta) y escribes lo siguiente:

```
git config user.name "nombre de usuario"
git config user.email usuario@gmail.com
```

El nombre de usuario va entre comillas dobles para que tome el espacio. No hacen falta comillas dobles en la configuración del correo ya que no posee. Repite esto en cada proyecto, cambiando el nombre y correo según lo prefieras y necesites.

### **Configuración General para todos los Proyectos:**

Puedes usar una configuración general para todos los proyectos que no hayan sido configurados de la forma anterior (ya que la configuración particular se toma en vez de la configuración general), la forma de hacerlo es:

```
git config --global user.name "nombre de usuario" 
git config --global user.email usuario@gmail.com
```

Puedes combinar estas configuraciones, usando el nombre de usuario configurado a nivel global y diferentes correos usando la configuración particular.

Saludos!